# Pyqt5 QtableWidget and integrated combobox fails to call a function when combobox items change

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, signals, qtablewidget

I have the below code :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class tabdemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(tabdemo, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,500)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.table()
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)


    def table(self):

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget() 
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)

        attr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
        i = 0
        for j in attr:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(j))
            combobox = QComboBox()
            for txt in ["Sinus","Triangle","Square"]:
                combobox.addItem(txt)
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, 1, combobox)
            i += 1

        self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.Table_itemchanged)

    def Table_itemchanged(self):
        print('Changed')

def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = tabdemo()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

It just puts a Qtablewidget with one column being labels and another column being comboboxes.
What I'm trying to do is when I modify the value of whatever combobox, I want call a function which, in this case, print 'changed' in the console.
the signal connection `self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.Table_itemchanged)` works fine when I edit the label part of the QtableWidget but it fails when I modify the combobox item.

Does anyone could explain me why and if it exists a solution to my issue.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `currentIndexChanged` signal of the combobox.

You can set a property on the combobox to store and recover which row (and column if you want) it belongs to.

```
    for j in attr:
        self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(j))
        combobox = QComboBox()
        for txt in ["Sinus","Triangle","Square"]:
            combobox.addItem(txt)
        combobox.setProperty('row', i)
        combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.Combo_indexchanged)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, 1, combobox)
        i += 1
```

and add a new slot:

```
def Combo_indexchanged(self):
    combo = self.sender()
    row = combo.property('row')
    index = combo.currentIndex()
    print('combo row %d indexChanged to %d' % (row, index))
```

Comment: Ok I see. That works. I'm wondering why I didn't  though about that. Thanks alot.

Comment: is it possible to directly send the combobox to the function called with connect? like `combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda x=combobox: self.Table_itemchanged(x)) `? I tried but it does not seem right.

Comment: my bad. I forget to put the state in the lambda function: `combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda state,x=combobox: self.Table_itemchanged(x))`